# An array with only one element comes to the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I try to process HttpPost request in my controller.

```
[HttpPost]
    [Route("device/configuration/config")]        
    public ActionResult<string> config([FromForm, Required] string class, [FromForm, Required] int account_id, [FromForm] string[] config, [FromForm] string creator_name)
```

As yoou see i want to get array of configs. 
In my test, I make a request for this endpoint, and pass the array in this form "config:"config1"", "config:"config2"". And everything works well. But when i call it from swagger I get not an array of configs, but an array with one item, where all configs are written separated by commas.

Curl from swagger

```
curl -X POST "localhost:7980/device/configuration/account_config" -H "accept: text/plain" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "device_class=someClass" -F "account_id=2" -F "config="123","321","222"" -F "creator_name=someCreator"
```

Comment: Please provide your swagger request.

Comment: curl -X POST "http://localhost:7980/device/configuration/account_config" -H "accept: text/plain" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "device_class=someClass" -F "account_id=2" -F "config="123","321","222"" -F "creator_name=someCreator"

Answer (score 1):

Can you try it like this:

```
curl -X POST "localhost:7980/device/configuration/account_config" -H "accept: text/plain" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "device_class=someClass" -F "account_id=2" -F "config=123" -F "config=321" -F "config=222" -F "creator_name=someCreator"
```

The problem is you have to send the array parameter 3 times.

You can send it like this also:

```
curl -X POST "localhost:7980/device/configuration/account_config?device_class=someClass&config=123&config=321&config=222&creator_name=someCreator" -H "accept: text/plain" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data"
```

Comment: it is not the same. Here I am sending config parameter 3 times: -F "config=123" -F "config=321" -F "config=222"

Comment: When I make RestRequest and call my endpiont I get ure curl. When I call my endpoint from swagger I get curl from my question. Why it happens?